# Duplicate/Incorrect Associations when Merging Tables with Power Pivot

Tags: excel, merge, powerquery, powerpivot

I am attempting to create documentation for a wiring project in Excel.

I created a small example where connector A is a 10 pin connector and connector B is a 5 pin connector. I have a table with information about connector A in one table (Pin Numbers and Pin Names), and another table containing information about how the pins on connector A associate the the pins on the two of the B connectors. I'd like to create a pivot table that allows me to show the Pin Names from connector A as a function of connector B ID and Pin Number.

As far as I can tell, this is a very basic example of how to merge data from two tables and PowerPivot should be capable of this, but the tutorials I have followed are not working for me for some reason! I was able to merge the tables using PowerQuery, which I could then use to show the data of in a Pivot table, but I am hoping to do this completely in PowerPivot.

The problem I am having is duplicate/incorrect associations in the PowerPivot Table.

Here is a snip (below) of the table I created using PowerQuery. This table is formatted exactly how I want it to be, but I don't think the method I used to create it will scale well with my project (when I have different permutations of connector A, for example).

[image: Pivot Table generated using PowerQuery method]

And below is the table I get from using PowerPivot.

**Note:** Each pin name is associated with every possible connector ID and pin number rather than the ones defined in my HarnessDefinition table.

[image: Pivot Table generated using PowerPivot method]

In PowerPivot, I have the two columns linked as shown below. As far as I am aware, this is all that should be required, but for some reason I am seeing every possibility under each connector A name, when there should really only be one association.

[image: PowerPivot Link]

I've thought to look at my source data, but it seems correct and analogous to the examples I have seen elsewhere. Here are my two source tables for reference.

[image: ConnectorDefinition]
[image: HarnessDefinition]

Please let me know if you can spot what I am getting wrong!

Comment: I found this post which seems to describe a very similar behavior. Indeed, if I add something in the values field of the PowerPivot generated table, it will clear out the duplicated results - the only problem is that I don't always want to use a value. 

For example, sometimes the item I am trying to drill down to, might be text.

I am somewhat convinced PowerPivot isn't the right tool for this after all, which seems unfortunate. I am interested if there are other solutions to this problem. PowerQuery seems like an okay option, but I don't think it's robust to changing collumn names, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72763465/power-pivot-relation-between-tables-from-data-model-created-with-power-query